# Ошибка в документации модуля multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, документация

В документации модуля multiprocessing есть раздел про [синхронизацию между процессами](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#synchronization-between-processes)

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock

def f(l, i):
    l.acquire()
    try:
        print('hello world', i)
    finally:
        l.release()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock = Lock()

    for num in range(10):
        Process(target=f, args=(lock, num)).start()
```

Сам пример предполагает последовательное выведение значений, но при запуске его из под idle получается примерно такой результат(который ещё и меняется при разных запусках)

```
hello world 0
hello world 1
hello world 2
hello world 7
hello world 3
hello world 5
hello world 6
hello world 4
hello world 9
hello world 8
```

Собственно совершенно непонятно из-за чего это происходит и как это можно исправить без .join()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, пример не предполагает соблюдения порядка выполнения. Блокировки гарантируют только то, что один процесс в один момент времени будет выводить данные на экран и у вас не получится чего-то такого:

```
hello world 0
hello world 1
hello worhledl 3
lo world 2
hello world 4
hello world 5
hello worldh 7
ello world 8
hello world 6
hello world 9
```

О чём в документации ясно написано:

> For instance one can use a lock to ensure that only one process prints
>   to standard output at a time:
>   ...
>   Without using the lock output from the different processes is liable
>   to get all mixed up.